# Do some beta meta sites have solid-black favicons? Is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-review, design, per-site-meta, favicon

Following some links and opening a bunch of meta posts from different per-site metas at the same time, I noticed an odd discrepancy in the icons:

[image]

The [Economics meta](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/) icon seems to be solid black, unlike some other beta meta site icons (to its left), and also unlike the [Economics main-site](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) icon which isn't solid blue but has a couple of white letters on it as I'd expect.

I'm not sure how many sites this affects, hence asking on main meta rather than Economics meta itself (also because I don't have an account on Economics SE, and a per-site meta post is less likely to be noticed).

**Why are some (at least one) meta beta icons solid black?**

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this on? I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEUOi.png) the letters "EC" in white on a black background, instead of a solid black icon as in your screenshot, on Brave Browser on macOS Big Sur. (Admittedly, Brave is not among the [supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/), but still.)

Comment: The [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/) [Meta icon](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/craftsmeta/Img/favicon.ico) is a very dark grey (namely #2d2d2d). Supposing the favicons are directly based on the regular icons.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Oddly, I see the favicon for the Economics Meta if I open it in a new tab in my browser window on one of my external monitors... but if I drag it onto my laptop (MacBook Pro) screen, it just appears solid black with no letters, as in in the screenshot. I have no idea what could cause that particular kind of discrepancy...

Comment: For Economics it's a [long standing problem](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1572/4816) ...

Comment: @Joachim: ...Interestingly, the "A&C" favicon on that page also looks slightly different on my external monitor vs. my MacBook screen. Specifically, on my external monitor, the ampersand looks something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Epsilon_Ampersand.png), while it and the letters look a lot more "pixelated" – whereas on my MacBook screen, the ampersand appears normal (`&`), while it and the letters look much "cleaner" (for lack of a better word). Same computer, same browser, just a different monitor... Huh. Maybe it has to do with Retina displays?

Comment: The [icon for Economics Meta](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/economicsmeta/Img/favicon.ico?v=eb0de12e7356) definitely looks solid to me.

Comment: @Glorfindel A main meta post gets more visibility/response than an Economics meta post :-)

Comment: It's now not solid black anymore (for me) but it has the wrong proportions, see e.g. https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Testing+for+Endogeneity%22 and the [SEDE homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (you have to scroll down a bit).